# Google Compute Engine: The resource 'projects/xxxx/global/networks/default' is not ready

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Google Cloud Kubernetes engine, it is awesome but my cluster suddenly got stuck in an error:

`Google Compute Engine: The resource 'projects/xxx/global/networks/default' is not ready`

Now I just want to delete it but I can't since the cluster is not configured.  I am continuously paying for a cluster that I can't use and I can't delete it.

Have any of you seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the network the cluster uses has become stuck in a state of "not ready", which is in turn affecting on your cluster.

Have you made any recent changes to the network?

One thing you could try  is rather than trying to delete the cluster via `gcloud container clusters delete` you could try deleting the instance group that governs that cluster, or reduce the amount of instances in that instance group to 0. If you are able to this, it would at least reduce your current expenditure for the resources you're currently not using.

There is also some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095429/cant-delete-underlying-vm-for-a-node-in-kubernetes) that suggests draining the pods before you attempt this.

If this works, you could then try recreating the default network/removing the troublesome current one.

Comment: thanks for the answer, my account was in billing inactive state but the error was about the network, anyways I was able to fix it by paying.